# Connect Browser Sync to windows 10

Tags: html, windows, html5-canvas, browser-sync

How can I connect browser-sync to the pages I am making in windows 10? I saw a course but it's using the MAC. I searched google, I asked my friends, but that did not work. I would appreciate any help you give me.

Answer (score 0):

First, either install Browsersync globally, or locally to your project (if you're using npm scripts) and then run one of the following commands.

browser-sync start [options]
browser-sync init
browser-sync reload
browser-sync recipe [name]